# Which events get fired when a record is removed from ExtJs 4.1 store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-stores

I am using ExtJS 4.1. I am using stores's remove() to delete the record from the store. I want to know which events get fired when you remove a record from the store. I looked at the sencha docs and I do not think there is a event for this specific requirement. This is the code I have written on the store's remove event. But its not working :(

```
Ext.define('MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MyModel',
    listners: {
        'remove': function(store, record, index, eOpts) {
            alert(record.data.MemberName);
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I misspelled listners :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From official documentation:

> remove( records )
>   Removes the given record from the Store, firing the
>   'remove' event for each instance that is removed, plus a single
>   'datachanged' event after removal.
>
> Available since: 1.1.0
>
> Parameters records : Ext.data.Model/Ext.data.Model[]
>    Fires: **beforesync bulkremove datachanged remove**